# Gorm Associations BeforeCreate Callback not working as expected

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have `Customer` struct

```
type Customer struct {
    Model
    Email                 string     `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Addresses             []Address
}

func (c *Customer) BeforeCreate() (err error) {
    if err := c.GenerateID(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.Marshal()
}
```

And `Address` struct

```
type Address struct {
    Model
    CustomerID         string
    Address1           string
}

func (a *Address) BeforeCreate() error {
// The ID is still generated, but the insert query has no `id` in it
    if err := a.GenerateID(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

`Model` struct

```
type Model struct {
    ID        string `gorm:"primary_key;type:varchar(100)"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}

func (model *Model) GenerateID() error {
    uv4, err := uuid.NewV4()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    model.ID = uv4.String()
    return nil
}
```

A Customer:

```
customer := &model.Customer{
    Email:     "a",
    Addresses: []model.Address{
        {
            Address1: "abc street",
        },
    },
}


if err := gormDb.Create(customer).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

`I got an error: Error 1364: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value` for the Address object

But if I remove the `Address` associations, things work. And the customer's `Id` is generated.

```
    customer := & model.Customer{
    Email:     "a",
    //Addresses: []model.Address{
        //{
            //Address1: "abc street",
        //},
    //},
}
```

How can I keep the `Address` associations and insert both successfully, and still using this ID-generation mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scope.SetColumn` to set a field’s value in `BeforeCreate` hook

```
func (a *Address) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
  scope.SetColumn("ID", uuid.New())
  return nil
}
```

Ref: https://v1.gorm.io/docs/create.html#Setting-Field-Values-In-Hooks

Comment: It seems doc link is not there anymore. Do you know an updated link? Your technique worked but when I earlier tried with `scope *gorm.DB` it never updated.

Comment: @arjun Link updated. For updated version you need to use hook method like `func(*gorm.DB) error` and make sure you are updating using pointer of current model. See here https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Hooks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tx.Statement.SetColumn` to set a field value in GORM hooks e.g. `BeforeCreate`. Following is the sample implementation.

```
func (s Product3) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    tx.Statement.SetColumn("Price", s.Price+100)
    return nil
}
```

Reference implementation link for GORM Github repo
https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/ac722c16f90e0e0dffc600c7f69e791c110d788c/tests/hooks_test.go#L306-L309

Reference link from GORM docs
https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Change-Updating-Values